# iOS 5 - Core Data UITableView Sections with NSDate Ranges

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios5, nsdate

I'd like to be able to create a `UITableView` using Core Data and `NSFetchedResultsController` that is divided up into a number of sections, each based on a range of dates, for example: within 5 days, within 10 days and within 20+ days, or something like that. I would be using an `NSDate` Core Data attribute called "date." I know how to divide the tableview into sections based off of each single date item, but not how to organize it like this. Can anyone help out with this? All I need is a bit of starting point.

As I've said, I'm using Core Data, `NSFetchedResultsController` and a `UIDatePicker` for the user to choose a date, which should then be put into the section.

Thanks a bunch everyone! I'm pretty new to iOS development, so please bear with me. :)